# Render a different template for a page if device is mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile

I am creating a new template in wordpress and I want to be able to render a different template for a page depending on the device which is requesting the page.

eg.

```
page request = "/home"
if desktop render template-home.php
if mobile browser render template-mobile-home.php
```

Any ideas on how I could do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are a lots of `Mobile Theme Switcher` plugins available to do the job for you. you can use any one which fits better for you. These plugins just switches the theme by detecting the device. Just take a look at [Any Mobile Theme Switcher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/any-mobile-theme-switcher/) and [Mobile theme switch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mobile-theme-switcher/) plugins. Hope it helps.

Also take a look at this for some [free wordpress mobile themes](http://slodive.com/freebies/free-wordpress-mobile-themes/). I'm using [WPtouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/screenshots/) for my blog. you may like [this](http://www.obox-design.com/wpmobile.cfm) too, it just converts a wordpress theme into a mobile friendly theme.

Comment: Thanks, yes, this could work, its a good idea. But I think I would still like to control which page-template is rendered.